# How to Check the Value of a Text Input If There Are Multiple Inputs with the Same Name?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have several text inputs that, once I hit submit, my PHP script receives the array $_POST['length'].

```
<form method="POST" action="myscript.php">
<input type="text" name="length[]" value="" onInput='checkinput();'>
<input type="text" name="length[]" value="" onInput='checkinput();'>
<input type="text" name="length[]" value="" onInput='checkinput();'>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to use a Javascript function to make sure that the user enters only numbers into each text box.  Each time something is typed into one of the boxes, the checkinput() function is executed.  How do I make the function grab the value from the right box that the user typed in so it can check that value?

Edit:  I want to allow numbers and decimals.

Comment: First, add `type="number"` to your inputs if you want only numbers in them.

Comment: `checkInput()` will get called with the element that's been clicked. Inside of it, you can get current element's value by using `this.target.value`.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 has the number-only validation you need. Just type `type="number"` in your input fields, instead of type text.

With regards to the JS part of the question - `checkInput()` will get called when you input something in the input boxes.

Inside of it you will get an event as a parameter, like so:

```
function checkInput(e) {}
```

You can get input's value by using `this` keyword, or the event object.

```
function checkInput(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    // check if value is a number
    // etc.
}
```

UPDATE:

Perhaps try data attributes. Your HTML would look like this:

```html
<form id="inputform">
  <input type="text" name="length[]" value="" data-number="1" />
  <input type="text" name="length[]" value="" data-number="2" />
  <input type="text" name="length[]" value="" data-number="3" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And JavaScript like this:

```
var formElem = document.querySelector("#inputform");
formElem.addEventListener("input", checkInput);

function checkInput(e) {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.number);
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

That will get you 1, 2 or 3 depending on the input that was modified. You can get also the value that the user has typed in, in `e.target.value`

Comment: I now have `onInput="checkinput(e);"` for each text box and `function checkinput(e){
 const text = e.target.value;
 alert(text);
}`  But I am not getting a pop-up.    What am I doing wrong?  I did get a pop up when I have `onInput="checkinput();"` and `function checkinput(){
 alert("blah");
}`

Comment: @freemarlie you don't need to ass e as parameter. It will get passed automatically. Also make the `onInput ` => `oninput`

Comment: So, use it like this: `<input type="number" name="length[]" value="" oninput='checkInput()'>`. And in `function checkInput(e) { e.target.value .... }`

Comment: Still not working.  Can you post the full working code?

Comment: I edited my question to say I wanted to allow numbers and decimals.

Comment: Is `oninput="checkInput();"` suppose to be missing in the inputs tag?  I tried the code and it is still not working.

Comment: It is supposed to be missing. That’s why you have addEventListener. I don’t know. I tried it on my local HTML plain environment and it worked perfectly. Please check also in your plain HTML environment. Then debug if something you did elsewhere causes the error.